# Serpent and Twofish library C

Tags: c, cryptography, twofish

I need to cipher an array of unsigned char (16 byte long) with Serpent and Twofish. I use two libraries -write in c- from the official website. I try to use them, but the ciphertext that i will obtain isn’t correct. For checking I use this [site](http://twofish.online-domain-tools.com/). I don't understand where is the mistake.
My code is:

```
keyInstance keyTwofish;
cipherInstance cipherTwofish;
unsigned char *buffer_out_twofish;

char path_file_twofish[DIM];
...
//Twofish
if(cipherInit(&cipherTwofish,MODE_ECB,NULL)!=TRUE)
{
   perror("[ERROR] Function module02: makeKey.\n");
   return 0;
}
//key_dim*8=128 and key is an unsigned char key [16] that contain key
makeKey(&keyTwofish, DIR_ENCRYPT, key_dim*8, key);
…
//Buffer in is unsigned char buffer_in[16] contain plaintext
//byte_for_file=16 than byte_for_file*8=128
//Buffer out is unsigned char buffer_out_twofish[16]
blockEncrypt(&cipherTwofish, &keyTwofish, buffer_in, byte_for_file*8, buffer_out_twofish);
```

For Serpent is the same implementation.

When I print a sizeof of variable’s type the result is:

```
Size of Char: 1
Size of Integer: 4
Size of Long: 8
```

And when I do:

```
printf("\nPrint Char Array: ");
for (int j = 0; j < byte_for_file; ++j)
   printf("%x ", buffer_in[j]);
printf("\nPrint long Array: ");
test(buffer_in, byte_for_file);
```

where

```
void test (unsigned long * a, int b)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < b/sizeof(long); ++i)
      printf("%lx ", a[i]);
}
```

I get this:

```
Print Char Array: 87 ae bd 58 71 75 1d 36 43 ab 1d ef 69 f5 54 d7 
Print long Array: 361d757158bdae87 d754f569ef1dab43
```

Comment: You are using the reference implementation and you test them *using a random website* ? Don't you think that is the wrong way around? What about comparing against the [Twofish](https://www.schneier.com/code/ecb_ival.txt) and  [Serpent](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~biham/Reports/Serpent/Serpent-128-128.verified.test-vectors) test vectors?

Comment: @Laura Renoldi: Not sure which implementation you use, but here: http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/MLEHMANN/Crypt-Twofish2-1.02/twofish.c, for example - it says makeKey should receive key encoded as hex string. So if your key is say 255 255 255 you should pass "FFFFFF".

Comment: Note that if I input everything as hexadecimals on the site (as you should) I do get the correct value for the given test vectors, both for twofish as for serpent (128 bit keys). Note that the key for serpent starts with an 8 instead of a zero.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I think that my cipher text is wrong not only for that site, also because for high number of plaintext all cipher text are like this: xxxx xxxx 0000 0000 xxxx xxxx 0000 0000, where xx is hex number.

Comment: @Giorgi Yes, my key is encoded as hex string.

Comment: Hmm, that's hard to answer without the code, but if it is C it may be a difference with regards to word size or endianess; I would not be surprised if it is.

Comment: it's also not easy to say- unless you show what you pass *in code* to those methods vs what you type on site

Comment: @MaartenBodewes the implementations that I use are the official ones, for serpent: [link](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~rja14/serpent.html) and for twofish: [link](https://www.schneier.com/twofish-download.html) - I’m a new user and i can’t insert more than 1 link in my question-.
I also think that this is a possible problem with word size and endianess. I've added two examples to my question to understand if this is effectively my problem.

Comment: If I read the NIST API correctly, doesn't the key need to be specified in hexadecimals? It's pretty unclear what the function should accept, but it seems unsigned char isn't it.

Answer (score 0):

The Implementation you use expects a key as keyLen/4 ASCII characters representing the hex values for the key.

So you should change the line:

```
makeKey(&keyTwofish, DIR_ENCRYPT, key_dim*8, key);
```

into

```
makeKey(&keyTwofish, DIR_ENCRYPT, strlen(key)*4, key);
```

Because Hexvalues like eg. 0x30313233343536373839 are not interpreted as 0123456789 but as 0x0300030103020303030403050306030703080309 and the Key 0123456789 would be interpreted as 0x00010203040506070809.